# connect ECONNREFUSED when I load config.json Amazon Web Services

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send push notification to the APNS_SANDBOX

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath(__dirname + '/config.json');
```

I write all credentials, and region. I am sure it works.

**then do the following:**

```
var sns = new AWS.SNS({endpoint:'https://s3.amazonaws.com'});
```

(it is actually wrong endpoint)

```
SNSMobilePush.prototype.pushIOS = function() {
  var deviceToken = ""; // This is 64 hex characters.
  var certificate = "";  // This should be in pem format with \n at the end of each line.
  var privateKey = "";  // This should be in pem format with \n at the end of each line.
  var applicationName = "Some app";
  this.demoNotification(Platforms.APNS_SANDBOX, certificate, privateKey, deviceToken,
    applicationName);
};

SNSMobilePush.prototype.demoNotification = function(platform, principal, credential, deviceToken, appName) {
  var params = {
    Name: appName,
    Platform: platform,
    Attributes: {
      PlatformPrincipal: principal,
      PlatformCredential: credential
    }
  };
  sns.createPlatformApplication(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
  });
};

    exports.pushExample = function() {
  var sample = new SNSMobilePush();
  sample.pushIOS('asd');
};
```

**then I make the following route:**

```
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
  snspush.pushExample();
  res.send('asd');
});
```

When I go to localhost:3000/a I have the following response:

```
    { [UnsignedContentSHA256NotAllowed: The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header must be a valid SHA256.]
  message: 'The provided \'x-amz-content-sha256\' header must be a valid SHA256.',
  code: 'UnsignedContentSHA256NotAllowed',
  time: Sat Dec 28 2013 14:51:24 GMT+0600 (ALMT),
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false }
```

***What is wrong with my headers?***

Unfortunately there is no working example with SNS at all in node js.

Comment: @AnilSivadas No I just start using APNS and GCM directly.

Comment: Any Solutions till now?